# Decrypting device driver

Tags: c, linux, encryption, drivers

I got a task to make a small image, encrypt it in the easiest way and write a decrypt driver.

Making an image:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=myFS bs=1024 count=60
mkfs.ext2 myFS
```

Encrypting it with XOR:

```
int main()
{
    std::fstream streamIn;
    std::fstream streamOut;

    const char key = 0b00001111;

    streamIn.open("myFS", std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::in);
    streamOut.open("newFS", std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::trunc | std::ios_base::out);

    char b;
    while (streamIn.read(&b, 1))
    {
        b ^= key;
        streamOut.write(&b, 1);
    }

    streamIn.close();
    streamOut.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Then, writing driver. It is based on device-mapper-target kernel module, so its main mapping function has this prototype:

```
static int sddm_target_map(struct dm_target *ti, struct bio *bio);
```

You see, I have a bio structure, and I think, that I should decrypt every byte it contains. What I have now:

```
struct bio_vec vec;
struct bvec_iter it;
unsigned int len;
char *addr;
unsigned int i;
unsigned long flag;

bio_for_each_segment(vec, bio, it)
{
    len = vec.bv_len;
    addr = bvec_kmap_irq(&vec, &flag);

    for (i = 0; i != len; ++i)
    {
        *(addr+i) ^= 0b00001111;
    }

    bvec_kunmap_irq(addr, &flag);
}
```

Of course, it doesn't work. Don't know why, but it even doesn't change anything in a query. I can just write `*(addr+i) ^= 0;` and nothing will be changed. If I apply this driver to a non-encrypted image it will be mounted well.

So my question is how to change data stored inside bio structure?

Comment: What is the `flags` value? Are you sure the last `bio_for_each_segment` argument isn't an `int` (This [documentation](https://lwn.net/Articles/26404/) may be obsolete)

Comment: @purplepsycho `flags` (flag) always equal to zero. Maybe I should set it to some value, but I don't know. I've tried to get address just with the help of `kmap_atomic` function (without using any flag), but nothing changed. There is an [implementation](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/bio.h#L496) of `bvec_kmap_irq`. What about documentation, yes, it is for older kernel. Actual one (4.10.*) has a bit different sources.

Comment: In which function is call the `bio_for_each_segment` macro? I guess it's called in `sddm_target_map`, but shouldn't be called from something like `sddm_target_read`?

Comment: @purplepsycho yes, this func is called in `sddm_target_map`. But it is an idea... I can override other functions. Full list is defined in [this](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/device-mapper.h#L158) structure. Mine `sddm_target_map` has `dm_map_fn` type. I guess `dm_map_request_fn` can be suitable

Comment: @purplepsycho nope. `dm_map_request_fn` is not called at all.

Comment: Okay, can you edit your post to show all `sddm_target_map` function, or event all driver if it's not too big?

Comment: @purplepsycho I've pasted it [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24274759/)

Comment: @purplepsycho do you have any ideas?

Comment: Well, I assume you've read this [page](http://techgmm.blogspot.fr/2012/07/writing-your-own-device-mapper-target.html). If you read from `/dev/mapper/sddm_target` instead of `/dev/loop6`, you can see: 1. that the xor operation is only performed on first device, 2. pages in `..._map` function are not loaded with data from disk image.

Comment: @purplepsycho Yes, I've put a glance on this article, it was my start point. 1. Yes, I mount `/dev/mapper/...` instead of `/dev/loop6` (otherwise I'm not able to use my driver). 2. It's a pity. So, do you have an idea, how to make changes within this devmapper target? There is a [dm-crypt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/md/dm-crypt.c) module. It is very complex, but if I'm not mistaken, it makes all encryption/decryption manipulation just inside [map-function](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/md/dm-crypt.c#L2042)